# Defining multiple local functions with "let over lambda" form in Scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, sicp, lexical-scope

I was curious about defining multiple lexically scoped functions in Scheme that can call each other. Working in SICP, I produced the following function using block structure to solve Exercise 1.8 (calculating cube-root using Newton's method):

```
(define (cbrt x)
  (define (good-enough? guess prev-guess)
    (< (/ (abs (- guess prev-guess))
          guess)
       0.001))
  (define (improve guess)
    (/ (+ (/ x (square guess))
          (* 2 guess))
       3))
  (define (cbrt-iter guess prev-guess)
    (if (good-enough? guess prev-guess)
        guess
        (cbrt-iter (improve guess)
                   guess)))
  (cbrt-iter 1.0 0.0))
```

This works fine, but it got me wondering how Scheme (and perhaps Common Lisp) might handle this same scenario using lexical scoping and the `let` form. I tried to implement it using `let` with the following kludgy code:

```
(define (cbrt x)
  (let ((calc-cbrt
         (lambda (guess prev-guess)
           (let ((good-enough?
                  (lambda (guess prev-guess)
                    (< (/ (abs (- guess prev-guess))
                          guess)
                       0.001))))
             (good-enough? guess prev-guess))
           (let ((improve
                  (lambda (guess)
                    (/ (+ (/ x (square guess))
                          (* 2 guess))
                       3))))
             (improve guess))
           (let ((cbrt-iter
                  (lambda (guess prev-guess)
                    (if (good-enough? guess prev-guess)
                        guess
                        (cbrt-iter (improve guess)
                                   guess)))))
             (cbrt-iter 1.0 0.0)))))
    (calc-cbrt 1.0 0.0)))
```

The problem that I see below is when `cbrt-iter` attempts to call the `good-enough?` procedure. Since the `good-enough?` procedure is only local to the scope of the first nested  `let` block, `cbrt-iter` has no way to access it. It seems that this can be solved by nesting the `cbrt-iter` function within the enclosing `let` of `good-enough`, but this seems  also very kludgy and awkward.

What is the `define` form doing that is different in this case? Is the `define` form expanding to `lambda` expressions instead of the "let over lambda" form (I recall something similar being done in the Little Schemer book using the form `((lambda (x) x x) (lambda (y) ...))`, but I am not sure how this would work). Also, by way of comparison, how does Common Lisp handle this situation - is it possible to use lexically scoped `defun`'s ?

Comment: As described in the answers there are other forms of `let` such as `let*` and `letrec` which allow a set of bindings in a let to 'see' previous (let*) or each other (letrec). https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to introduce a new procedure `calc-cbrt` - you could just call `calc-iter` instead.

Second, the meaning of `define` and `let` are quite different.  `Define` *installs* the definitions into the local scope, as in your example.  However, `let` expressions are just syntactic sugar for `lambda` expressions (see SICP section 1.3 for details).  As a result (and as you mention), variables declared via `(let (<decl1> ...) <body>)` are only visible inside `<body>`.  So, your pattern of `(let <decls1> <body1>) (let <decls2> <body2>) ...` doesn't work, since none of the definitions will "survive" to be seen in other scopes.

So, we should write something like this:

```
(define (cbrt x)
   (let ((good-enough? (lambda ...))
         (improve (lambda ...))
         (cbrt-iter (lambda ...)))
     (cbrt-iter 1.0 0.0)))
```

Now, at least, the call to `cbrt-iter` can see the definition of `cbrt-iter`.

But there's still a problem.  When we evaluate `(cbrt-iter 1.0 0.0)`, we evaluate the body of `cbrt-iter` where `guess` and `prev-guess` take the values 1.0 and 0.0.  But, in the body of `cbrt-iter`, the variables `improve` and `good-enough?` aren't in scope.

You might be tempted to use nested `let`s, which is often a good choice:

```
(define (cbrt x)
   (let ((good-enough? (lambda ...))
         (improve (lambda ...)))
     (let ((cbrt-iter (lambda ...)))
       (cbrt-iter 1.0 0.0))))
```

The problem is that cbrt-iter needs to call itself, but it's not in scope until the body of the inner `let`!

The solution here is to use `letrec`, which is like `let` but makes the new bindings visible inside all the declarations as well as the body:

```
(define (cbrt x)
   (let ((good-enough? (lambda ...))
         (improve (lambda ...)))
     (letrec ((cbrt-iter (lambda ...)))
       (cbrt-iter 1.0 0.0))))
```

We can even use `letrec` to create mutually recursive procedures, just as we could with `define`.

Unfortunately, it would take me some time to explain how `letrec` and `define` actually work, but here's the secret: they both use *mutation* internally to create circularity in the environment data structure, allowing recursion.  (There is also a way to create recursion using only `lambda`, called the *Y combinator*, but it's rather convoluted and inefficient.)

Luckily, all these secrets will be revealed in Chapter 3 and Chapter 4!

For another perspective, you might take a look at [Brown University's online PL class](http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1730/2012/), which basically goes straight to this topic (although it omits `define`), but I find that SICP is better at forcing you to understand the sometimes complex environment structures that are created.

Comment: You mentioned the Y-combinator - I remember seeing this in the Little Schemer book using the looping combinator (i.e. `(lambda (x) x x)`). Just to be clear - this is not how `define` is actually implemented?

Comment: No!  The `define` form _adds_ a binding to the current environment, and the `letrec` form extends the environment with your new variable bound to an undefined value, then sets the value to the value you specified.  These both use mutation (i.e., aren't _purely functional_) under the hood, but are far more sensible for practical programming than using the Y combinator.

Comment: Scheme actually defines internal `define`s to be *completely equivalent* to `letrec` (in R5RS, http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.2.2) or `letrec*` (in R6RS, http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.3)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will get some more practice using the `letrec` form.